# Azure Pipelines Modules Conflict

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently trying to run powershell script via Azure Pipelines. While running the script from a Project In Azure Dev Ops I am getting following error :

```
WARNING: Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the 
same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can
 use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure 
Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found
```

This is Azure Hosted pipeline and I do not have possibility to modify loaded modules other than Pipeline definition itself. In the pipeline definition I did add following

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      
      Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts 
      
      
      Write-Host "Az Installed"
```

I doublechecked my script and it DOES NOT use any of AzureRM cmdlets, I do not really understand from where pipeline takes AzureRM module, when it is not imported by pipeline definiton or by script itself.

Can someone please explain ?

BR,
Matthias

Answer (score -1):

You need run below power shell script to install the modules

```
Install-Module -Name Az.Accounts -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```